# API from pythonanywhere.com not working as expected

Tags: python, python-requests

Hola estoy haciendo tests con https://pythonanywhere.com y he intentado crear una función para cambiar las tareas programadas.

Aquí la documentación de la API: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/API/

Primero obtengo el id de la tarea programada

```
    username = os.environ.get('USER', 'XXX')
    token = os.environ.get('API_TOKEN', 'XXX')

    response = requests.get(
        'https://www.pythonanywhere.com/api/v0/user/{username}/schedule/'.format(
            username=username
        ),
        headers={'Authorization': 'Token {token}'.format(token=token)}
    ) 


    idcron = response.json()[0].get("id")
```

Y luego intento cambiar la hora

```
        params = {'command': response.json()[0].get("command"),
            'enabled': response.json()[0].get("enabled"),
            'interval': response.json()[0].get("interval"),
            'hour': 11,
            'minute': 25
        }

        response = requests.put(
            'https://www.pythonanywhere.com/api/v0/user/{username}/schedule/{idcron}'.format(
                username=username, idcron=idcron
            ),
            headers={'Authorization': 'Token {token}'.format(token=token)},
            params=params
        )
```

Y tengo el siguiente fallo

```
    >>> response.text
    '{"interval":["This field is required."],"command":["This field is required."],"minute":["This field is required."]}'
```

He probado de todo pero siempre tengo esta respuesta.

PD: Estoy ejecutando este scrip dentro de la consola de pythonanywhere en la misma cuenta que quiero cambiar la tarea programada.

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) , ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para así poder ayudarte mejor, te recomiendo que traduzcas tu pregunta ya que este es un sitio en **español**

Comment: Traduce tambien tu título.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado los siguientes problemas:

- Los endpoints terminan en `/`: `/api/v0/user/{username}/schedule/{id}/`, sino lo pones causa una redireccion que genera problemas.
- Si vas a enviar un diccionario debes usar a traves de json.

```
# ...

response = requests.put(
    "https://www.pythonanywhere.com/api/v0/user/{username}/schedule/{idcron}/".format(
        username=username, idcron=idcron
    ),
    headers={
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Token {token}".format(token=token),
    },
    json=params
)

print(response.json())
```